# JavaFx Equivalent to Graphics context.rotate() for nodes

Tags: java, javafx, transform

If I am drawing in a canvas, I can rotate the coordinate system of the graphicscontext without rotating anything that is already drawn in the corresponding canvas, same with translations.

Is there anything similar possible in a group? If I just rotate and translate it's children I don't get the right effect because translations orient themselves on the unrotated system of the group.

If not, is there anything like a 3d canvas with that functionality?

Comment: The classes in the [`javafx.scene.transform`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/transform/package-summary.html) package are probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Combined with [`Node.getTransforms()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTransforms()).

Comment: @Slaw I tried it. Does exactly what I wanted with Affine.append. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TimB.: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188); consider including a [mcve] that exhibits the  effect you describe.

Comment: @trashgod. Ok, I will do that tomorrow evening.

Answer (score 0):

As Slaw pointed out, what i was looking for were the classes in the package javafx.scene.transform.

Here is an example: Let's say I want a Line starting from (200, 200) with a length of 200 in direction 60 degrees from the x-axis. This would be not so hard to do without the transform package aswell but it shall only serve as an easy example.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.transform.Affine;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        // Does not work as intended
        Line line1 = new Line(0,0, 200, 0);
        line1.setTranslateX(200);
        line1.setTranslateY(200);
        line1.setRotate(60);

        // Does work as intended.
        Line line2 = new Line(0, 0, 200, 0);
        Affine affine = new Affine();
        affine.appendTranslation(200, 200);
        affine.appendRotation(60);
        line2.getTransforms().add(affine);

        group.getChildren().addAll(line1, line2);

        stage.show();
    }
}
```